# Augmented reality in mono touch

Tags: mono, xamarin.ios, augmented-reality

I'm developing a typical "Windows GUI" based app for iPhone using MONO technologies. I need to add a little AR based functionality to it. It is just about opening up the camera, and showing information to the user regarding nearby businesses.

How can I do this using mono?

Answer (score 1):

Of course it is possible. I have created a project and works very nice. It is quite complicated and I would need three pages to explain it and, the time to do it which I do not have.

In general, you need to look into:

- CLLocationManager for location and
  compass.
- MapKit, if you want to provide
  reverse geocoding information.
- Implement an overlay    view over the
  UIImagePickerController    which will
  act as your canvas.
- And of    course, drawing.

I hope these guidelines will get you started.